# Displaying number of records updated count for each 5 seconds as a progress while actual updating in progress

Tags: asp.net

I have a button. When i click on a button, am updating data in a table which takes 15 to 20 minutes through jquery ajax call. In my updation logic am using bulk collect concept and updating 5000 records at a time and i am updating another log table where i am updating total number of records updated after for each 5000 records updation.

My requirement is i want to display number of records updated count progresively to the user while actual update is in progress.
For displaying count i have used Javascript setInterval function which uses jquery ajax call to get the count for each 5 seconds and display count in lablel. I am placing my code as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x;
    function Showdialog() {
        //alert('called');
        var sAppId = $("#<%=hdnAppid.ClientID %> ").val();
        //debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "AutoReconWithProgress.aspx/UpdateData",
            data: "{'sAppId':'" + sAppId + "'}",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#ctl00_middleContent_divLoader").dialog(
                   {
                       modal: true,
                       width: 300,
                       height: 200,
                       buttons: {
                           Close: function () {
                               clearInterval(x);
                               $("#ctl00_middleContent_divLoader").dialog('close');
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   );
                x = setInterval(autoReconCount, 5000);
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#ctl00_middleContent_divLoader").dialog('close');
                clearInterval(x);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (typeof data.d !== "undefined") {
                    $("[id$='ctl00_middleContent_lblThread2']").html(data.d);
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

    }

    function autoReconCount() {
                var sAppId = $("#<%=hdnAppid.ClientID %> ").val();
                //debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "AutoReconWithProgress.aspx/GetAutoCount",
                    data: "{'sAppId':'" + sAppId + "'}",
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (typeof data.d !== "undefined") {                                
                            $("#lblCount").html(data.d);

                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });

            }
</script>

<div id="divLoader" title="Please Wait" runat="server" style="display: none">
    <center>
        <span style="font-size: medium; font-family: Zurich BT;">Auto Reconciliation is in progress..</span>
        <br />
        <span style="font-size: medium; font-family: Zurich BT;">Reconciled Count: </span>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCount"  runat="server" CssClass="labelText" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:Label>
    </center>
</div>

<asp:Button CssClass="buttonCs" ID="btnSubmitAuto" Text="Auto Reconciliation" runat="server"
                        OnClientClick="Showdialog(); return false;" />
```

When i click on button, i am call showdialog function. In that before send event i am opening dialog box where i have lable to disply dynamic updated count.

AutoReconWithProgress.aspx/UpdateData url is to update data.
My problem my dynamic updated count displaying afeter completion of actual call.
My requirement is i want to dynamically disply the updated records count when actual update is in progress.
Please guide me.

Comment: Your user will sit and see the screen for 20 minutes? Are you sure this is right approach?

Comment: Yes that is the business requirement only.

Answer (score 0):

and if you did a while checking the AJAX request. for example:

```
var req; //receives the XMLHttpRequest

while(req.status != 200){
    autoReconCount();
}
```

while the request does not return the success code 200 it continues to run the function autoReconCount(); , and if you want, you can set the interval the same way you did above

Comment: I have already set the interval in before send event to get the updated count for each 5 seconds. Could you please help me with code where i am doing wrong.

Comment: on debuging, this line call the method autoReconCount?????   x = setInterval(autoReconCount, 5000);

Comment: Thank yop for your help. I tried set interval function x = setInterval(autoReconCount, 5000);  autoReconCount(); function gets executing after the completion of main function Showdialog().  Hence count is displaying after all the process completed.

Comment: My suggestion for you is to drop the SetInterval and do a While to check the status of the HTTP call, and thus call the AutoRecount function. by what I see in your code the autoRecount function is being called only once in the BeforeSend. and you need it to be called until the HTTP request is completed. I think While would solve the problem